# Unable to get dependency in an internal repository

Tags: maven, repository

We are using Maven 3.0.3.  We have deployed a JAR file to an internal repository at

http://maven/maven_repo/repositories/release/org/openqa/selenium/server/selenium-server/0.9.2/selenium-server-0.9.2-standalone.jar

I have then included this dependency ...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openqa.selenium.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Also, in my ~/.m2/settings.xml file, I have our internal repository ...

```
            <repository>
                <id>mycoInternalRelease</id>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <name>myco Internal Repository</name>
                <url>http://maven/maven_repo/repositories/release</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
```

Despite all this, when I run my pom, I get the error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myco-productplus-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project myco-productplus:myco-productplus-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT:The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.openqa.selenium.server:selenium-server:jar:0.9.2, org.openqa.selenium.server:selenium-server-coreless:jar:0.9.2: Could not find artifact org.openqa.selenium.server:selenium-server:jar:0.9.2 in mycoInternalRelease (http://maven/maven_repo/repositories/release) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

How can I heal the pain?  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your artifact is named "selenium-server-0.9.2-standalone.jar" you might need to add `<classifier>standalone</classifier>` to your dependency declaration in your pom.