# Having trouble starting selenium server as a Maven task

Tags: maven, selenium

I'm using Maven 3.0.3.  I'm having trouble starting a Selenium server as part of a pre-integration-test phase because Maven isn't able to find a dependency.  I've included this ...

```
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.openqa.selenium.server</groupId> 
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId> 
        <version>0.9.2</version> 
        <classifier>standalone</classifier> 
    </dependency>
```

which is successfully being read from an internal repository, but I'm greeted with the error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myco-productplus-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project myco-productplus:myco-productplus-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT:Could not find artifact org.openqa.selenium.server:selenium-server-coreless:jar:0.9.2 in mycoInternalRelease (http://maven/maven_repo/repositories/release) -> [Help 1]
```

Does anyone know where I can get the Selenium-coreless JAR file, org.openqa.selenium.server.selenium-server-coreless, version 0.9.2 (or alternatively, know how I can start up a Selenium server)?  Here is the plugin I use for starting up the Selenium server ...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <browser>*firefox</browser>
                <suite>src/test/resources/selenium-test-suite.html</suite>
                <startURL>http://localhost:${tomcat.servlet.port}/${project.artifactId}</startURL>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase> 
                    <goals> 
                        <goal>start-server</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <background>true</background> 
                        <logOutput>true</logOutput>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                ...
            </executions>
```

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: **Dave**, you've asked this question [recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164098) and accepted the answer. Something went wrong with the solution provided? If so, comment in the original message.